# importando backup pelo terminal MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, importação

Ontem tava fazendo um testes no PostgreSQL de inserção e backup importação e exportação e o PostgreSQL tem um comando de importação do SQL da seguinte forma:

```
psql# \i backup.sql
```

Tem algo relacionado a isso no `MariaDB(MySQL)` sem ser como *plain* pelo terminal do mesmo?

```
MariaDB [teste]> ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *MariaDb* você pode usar o `source` ou simplesmente `\.` para executar um arquivo `.sql`, por exemplo:

```
MariaDB> source file.sql

MariaDB> \. file2.sql
```

Há outras formas de executar um *script* também:

```
user@pc: mysql -u USUARIO -p < file.sql
```

Você também pode utilizar o [mysqlimport](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlimport/), por exemplo:

```
user@pc: mysqlimport [OPTIONS] DATABASE file.sql file2.sql ...
```